# On which MAC address Docker interface with the internet?

Tags: networking, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to set up a container with docker.
The container can access the internet while I'm under my home network which doesn't have any filter, but fails to connect while under the university network (I can't even `docker run ubuntu ping 8.8.8.8`. I just get nothing). From my experience the university network drops everything that's not on port :80 and is not an http/https/ftp(and similar protocols) request.

I can ask for a specific MAC address to not be filtered.
With which MAC address does docker interface with internet?

Does it use my wireless board? I think it creates a new interface, but I have no idea if all the containers traffic goes through it.

Which MAC address should I ask to unlock in order for my containers not to be filtered?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can ask for a specific MAC address to not be filtered. With which MAC address does docker interface with internet?

When communicating with the outside world, Docker is using the MAC address and source IP address of your host.  If you are connected to the University network using your wireless NIC, then this is the NIC that Docker containers use for external connectivity.

Docker creates a bridge device on your system named `docker0`.  All containers connect to this bridge, and use a private range of ip addresses.  Communication external to your host happens via NAT rules configured using iptables (you can view them by running `iptables -t nat -S`).  These rules make traffic originating in Docker containers appear to originate from your host instead.

Comment: I read about the docker0 interface, but I was not sure which physical interface it was using. Thanks for the info. I'll request to have the wireless card MAC be "released". I'll accept this answer the moment I can check it works(should take a couple of days at most)

Comment: Note that `docker0` is not "using" a physical interface in any meaningful sense.  Your host is routing packets out your default interface because of the NAT rules.

Comment: It might take more time than expected to have my MAC unlisted. Accepting for now(doesn't seem fair to make you wait for it), I'll come back later if it doesn't work. I also believe it might be solved by changing the way docker connects to the internet to bridging.